# Split data into training and testing not randomly

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I want to split my dataset into two parts, 75% for training and 25% for testing. There are two classes.
And I have another dataset that has only one instance of one class, rest all instances belong to second class.
So I dont want to split randomly. I want to make sure, if there is only one instance of one class, it should be in training. Any ideas how to do it. I know I have to select the indices, but i don't know how. 
Right now , I am doing this, which is selecting first 75% as training and remaining as testing

```
train_data = df[:int((len(df)+1)*.75)] 
test_data = df[int(len(df)*.75+1):]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help : `GroupKFold`. Find the sklearn doc there :

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a stratified train and test split: sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Answer (score 0):

Does your dataset change in terms of input, or will it be the same amount of data consistently? If the latter, you could simply assign whatever number is 75% of your total set as your second argument for the splice method. For instance, if you have 100 items, you'd assign your train_data = df[0:75:] and the other test_data = df[76:].

But without a model or shortened script, I don't think I can do much more.

Comment: The dataset changes in terms of input. the number of instances is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

train_data = df[:int(len(df) * .75)]
test_data = df[int(len(df) * .75)::int(len(df) * .25) - 1]

It worked for me when tested against a list of 10 integers.

Comment: Can you please explain this line                                                  
  test_data = df[int(len(df) * .75)::int(len(df) * .25) - 1]

Comment: Sure. It helps in this case to read this splice backwards. The third and last argument skips over the first 25% of the list, then the first argument reads the rest which happens to be the remaining 75%. And there is no second argument since there doesn't need to be one, which is why it's left blank.

Comment: Also, if this answer works for you, then please select it as such and close the question.